# Google Maps API v3 - ContextMenu inside infowindow

Tags: google-maps, contextmenu

I'm using ContextMenu.js to create a context menu for a few options on right-clicking the map. The plugin is here:
http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2012/04/create-google-maps-context-menu.html

And here is a portion of my code:

```
/* Right click marker for location specific context menu */
            google.maps.event.addListener(contextMenu, 'menu_item_selected', function(latLng, eventName){
                switch(eventName){
                    case 'directions_from_click':
                        //Populate start field with the marker location
                        showDirections();
                        geocoder.geocode({latLng: latLng}, function(results, status) {
                          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results[0]) {
                              fAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
                              $('#start').val(fAddress);

                            }
                          }
                        });
                        $('#panelWrapper').focus();
                        break;
                    case 'directions_to_click':
                        //Populate start field with the marker location
                        showDirections();
                        geocoder.geocode({latLng: latLng}, function(results, status) {
                              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                if (results[0]) {
                                  fAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
                                  $('#end').val(fAddress);
                                }
                              }
                            });
                            $('#panelWrapper').focus();
                        break;
                }
            });
```

But this only applies to right-clicking the map. I'd like to take this same context menu and use it for links inside of my infowindow. For instance, a link that says "Directions" (see image), and then a context menu appears on click. How would I go about doing this? I

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we ended up removing this requirement because of a quick turnaround.